# Migrating existing groups from Commons 2.x to Commons 3

Tags: migrations, 7

I've just installed Commons 3 on a sandbox server and am curious where to begin migrating groups data over. I realize this is may also apply generic D6 to D7, but is there additional consideration for a Drupal Distribution? What steps should I take to move content and groups from Common 2.x to Commons 3.x?

That is, how can I move existing groups from Commons 2.x into Commons 3.x that will include content types attached to those groups (discussions, postings, events, wikis)?

I know that Activity Streams are different between these versions and we can live with out that, but I'd like to bring over content attached to the appropriate groups and users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Commons maintainer japerry is in a team that created 
[Commons Migration](http://drupal.org/project/commons_migration) module exactly for your task.

> Posted by nateswart on March 18, 2013 at 9:46pm
>
> Provide a migration path from Commons 2.x to 3.x

It uses [Migrate](http://drupal.org/project/migrate) with [Drupal-to-Drupal data migration](http://drupal.org/project/migrate_d2d) to get the job done. Sadly, it's still in early development, and according to [this feature request](http://drupal.org/node/1868854) not quite finished yet. But at the very least you can see in code what approach original developers use.

Comment: A very good suggestion and one I'll be watching. I was hoping for something production ready. Though +1 for leading me to migrate_d2d

Comment: @Richard If one of the maintainer didn't got finished solution, I guess it's hard to get better than that. You can download what's there from git and try to use, just make a lot of backups ;)

Answer (score 1):

When I had that same task, I ended up creating a little custom module based on just [migrate_d2d](https://drupal.org/project/migrate_d2d). The code is obviously specific to our content type structure, but well documented so as to be useful as a template for developing your own custom migration module.

You can find our code here: module [migrate_d2d_edgeryders](https://github.com/edgeryders/edgeryders-commons/tree/master/sites/all/modules/migrate_d2d_edgeryders). (Unfortunately it does not have its own repo, so you will have to download and install its three files from there manually.)